# Angular $q.all() console.log output order timing not making sense to me

Tags: angularjs, q

I have this service

```
angular.module("myApp").service("xhrService", [
    "$q", function($q) {
        var promises = [];

        return {
            push: function(promise) {
                promises.push(promise);
            },
            process: function($scope) {
                $q.all(promises).then(function() {
                    $scope.$emit("loading:dataReady");
                    promises = [];                     
                });
            }
        }
}]);
```

This code in a parent controller

```
$scope.$on("loading:dataReady", function () {
    console.log("Data Ready");
});
```

This code in a child controller

```
var getEstimatedExpenseTypes = $http.get("api/estimatedExpenseType").then(
    function (response) {
        console.log("getEstimatedExpenseTypes Success");
        $scope.estimatedExpenseTypes = response.data;
    },
    function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
    }
);


xhrService.push([getEstimatedExpenseTypes]);

xhrService.process($scope);
```

The problem I'm having is that the console.log's are not happening in the order that I'm expecting. In chrome, with this code, I see "Data Ready" first, and then "getEstimatedExpenseTypes Success". Shouldn't it be the other way around?

I thought that $q.all().`then(...)` code would run after the promises in `all()`. But judging by the order in which the console is getting written to, that doesn't appear to be the case

What's going on here. I'm not understanding something correctly about how this works

***Update:*** Fixed `$on` code placement

Comment: shouldn't it be like `$q.all(promises)` rather `$q.all([promises])`, since `promises` is already an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q.all` expects an array of promises, the mentioned code makes it an `array of array` of promises

`xhrService.push([getEstimatedExpenseTypes]);` pushes an array `[getEstimatedExpenseTypes]` into the array `var promises = [];`

replacing `xhrService.push([getEstimatedExpenseTypes]);` with `xhrService.push(getEstimatedExpenseTypes);` makes the right ordering of execution.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Lbbd8j/)

**EDIT**

if you want to push array of promises from controller, you can change the push method in your service as,

```
push: function(promise) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(promises, promise);
}
```

then you can write something like

```
xhrService.push([getEstimatedExpenseTypes]);
```

**EDIT**

if you want to add both single and array of promises to your service, something like this should work

```
push: function(promise) {
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(promise) == "[object Object]")
        promises.push(promise);
    else if if(Object.prototype.toString.call(promise) == "[object Array]")
        Array.prototype.push.apply(promises, promise);
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem. I wonder if there'd be a way to be able to push an array of $http's at once from the controller, for the sake of less lines of code

Comment: Interesting, when using ```Array.prototype.push.apply(promises, promise);``` , "Data Ready" gets output to the console before the $http promises resolve, causing the original problem I had. Unless it's because i'm not always passing an array to the push method. sometimes i only have one xhrRequest on the view